# How to link internally on an html page to inside an object tag

Tags: html

I have a microsoft .doc file which I converted to html (by clicking save as html). That .doc file had within it internal links to other parts of the document, and thus the new html page did as well.

I then embeded this html file inside another one with a object tag. Now the links don't work. Why exactly is this and can it be fixed?

Comment: If you are using anchor tags (name attribute) then it won't probably work as the object container prevents the anchors to position the window

Comment: So, how can I link to a line inside the object tag?

Comment: why did you embed the html inside another one? can't you just copy and paste the other html into the current one? if you do that, the anchor links should still work.